# Formula for $f^{-1}(w)$ in terms on integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question:

> Let $f$ be a one-to-one holomorphic map from a region $D_1$ onto a region $D_2$. Suppose that $D_1$ contains the closure of the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$. Prove that for $w \in f(\mathbb{D})$, the inverse function $f^{-1}(w)$ is given by
>
> $$f^{-1}(w) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{f'(z)z}{f(z) - w} dz$$

My solution goes as follows: suppose that $f^{-1}(w) = z_w$. Then, we must show that the integral above is equal to $z_w$. Since $f$ is injective, the integrand above is holomorphic at all points except at $z = z_w$. Let $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_w)^n$ be the Taylor Expansion at $z_w$ that is valid for $z$ near $z_w$. In particular, for $z$ small enough (by performing polynomial division if you'd like) we see that

$$\frac{f'(z)z}{f(z) - w} = \frac{z_w}{z-z_w} + G(z)$$

Where $G(z)$ is analytic (and so bounded) near $z_w$. Since the integrand is holomorohic inside the contour except at $z_w$ we may deform the contour and note that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{f'(z)z}{f(z) - w} dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_\epsilon} \frac{f'(z)z}{f(z) - w} dz$$

Where $C_\epsilon$ is a circle centered at $z_w$ of radius $\epsilon$ inside $\mathbb{D}$. We can make $\epsilon$ small enough so that

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_\epsilon} \frac{f'(z)z}{f(z) - w} dz = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_\epsilon} \frac{z_w}{z - z_w} + G(z) dz = z_w$$

Where the last equality comes from the Cauchy Integral Formula and Cauchy's Theorem. This proves the desired result.

Does the above argument seem to make sense? Is there another solution to this problem that does not involve Taylor Expanding around a point? The integrand kind of looks like something from the argument principle, but I could not figure out how to use this prove the statement.

Comments and other solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just a change of variables - if $f(\partial \mathbb D)=\Gamma, f^{-1}(w)=g(w)$, $g$ is analytic inside and on the analytic Jordan curve $\Gamma$ so by Cauchy we have:

$2\pi ig(w)=\int_{\Gamma}\frac{g(\zeta)}{\zeta-w}d\zeta$

But now changing variables $\zeta=f(z), \zeta \in \Gamma$ means $|z|=1$ and then $d\zeta=f'(z)dz, g(\zeta)=z$ so subtituting we get precisely the required formula.

Comment: I like it, thank you for the solution.

Comment: happy to be of help